# How to access an array instance variable from another class?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm extremely new to JavaScript and I'm doing an assignment for my degree. I have an array in one class, that has information in it, and from another class I'm trying to call that array so I can display the information in it.

```
class Election {

constructor(newYear) {
    this.year = newYear;
    this.allMyElectorates = [];
}

    addElectorate (electorateRegion) {
        let newElectorate = new Electorate(electorateRegion)
        this.allMyElectorates.push(newElectorate)

        return newElectorate;
    }

    sortElectoratesByRegion() {
        this.allMyElectorates.sort();
    }
};
```

This is the class with the array in it, where I am storing my Electorates I add.

```
class Elections {

constructor(country) {
    this.allMyElections = []
}   

getElectorateByRegion () {
        let theElectorate, result;
        result = "(A) All Electorates by Region<br>";
        //this.sortElectoratesByRegion();
        for (theElectorate of this.allMyElectorates){
            result += theElectorate.toString() + "<br>";
        }

        return result;
    }

    getAll () {
        let result;
        result = this.getElectorateByRegion() + '<br>';

        return result;
    }
};
```

This is the class I am trying to call my array in. I'm trying to call the array in the 'getElectoratebyRegion' method, but of course, this.allMyElectorates doesn't work because there's no parameter in that class as such.

Sorry for the wall of text - I tried looking around everywhere but couldn't find anything on this. Keep in mind I'm VERY new at this, so my terminology may even be off.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript. I've removed the irrelevant tag for you.

Comment: You don't "call" arrays, you refer to them or use them. You "call" functions and methods.

Comment: `allMyElectorates` is associated with instance of your class. Pass reference of this object and you will be able to push/manipulate array

Comment: create the method that get all array elements and call the method using an object of another class

Comment: Your `Elections` class has an `allMyElections` array, which presumably would contain instances of `Election` (though you haven't shown anything doing that). So you'll have as many `allMyElectorates` arrays as you have `Election` instances in your `allMyElections` array. You'd use `allMyElectorates` *via* one or all of those `Election` instances.

Comment: HI all. Thanks for the responses. I understand that I need to create a reference, in order to make a call method to use the array elements, however, as an extreme novice, I'm not sure what code that will look. 

Is anyone able to provide a working method so I can learn from that and understand what I must do?

Thanks all :)